# I can't get any custom url cursor to work

Tags: css, svg

This is my first bug so be gentle. I just can't get a custom url cursor to work. When using a standard one like "pointer" everything works, but when using a url, either local or remote it just does nothing.

I've come across similar issues being solved here but none of them are working for me (checking the sizing, file type, url location...)

My goal was for it to appear when hovering an svg image. I've tried styling it inside the svg file itself, it works fine for "pointer" but not for "url".
I've tried adding the svg file inside an  tag, and styling the cursor inside it, works with "pointer", doesn't work with "url".
Tested on different browsers, none of them respond to it.

What am I doing wrong? See below some of the stuff I've tried:

```
<svg ...>
<style>
    svg {cursor: url(01ssss3326.cur);}
</style>
</svg>
```

doesn't work

```
<svg ...>
<style>
    svg {cursor: url(http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-extern.php?id=107471);}
</style>
</svg>
```

doesn't work

```
<body>
    <img src="prettyinternet.svg" alt="" style="cursor: url(http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-extern.php?id=109070);">
</body>
```

doesn't work

```
<body>
    <img src="prettyinternet.svg" alt="" style="cursor: pointer;">
</body>
```

this works

```
<svg ...>
    <style>
        svg {cursor: pointer;}
    </style>
 </svg>
```

this works too

Answer (score 0):

Is that working in this way? I guess you are just missing `""`

```
 <svg ...>
    <style>
        svg {cursor: url("01ssss3326.cur");}
    </style>
    </svg>
```

This is another example which I used in one of my project and it works. I am passing it in my css

```
cursor:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'  width='32' height='38' viewport='0 0 100 100' style='fill:black;font-size:19px;'><text y='50%'></text></svg>") 16 0,auto;
```

Comment: Hi Evren, I've tried with quotes" " single quote ' ' no quote, nothing works.

Comment: However, with the example you've provided I see some progress: your css works for me when I add it on an external CSS sheet, but it doesn't work with inline styling which is what I was aiming for.

My examples aren't working even when on an external CSS sheet.

Comment: Well I do not know what to change in inline-styling to make it work but I would recommend you to not using inline-styling if you do not have specific reason. Especially with cursor since you will probably want to change it sometimes on hovers.

Comment: The problem wasn't the inline since it was also not working on external CSS sheets, and the "pointer" was working fine even inline. BUT I've solved it! It happens that specifying a fallback cursor is mandatory apparently. That was also on your code and I didn't have it in mine, now that I've made that change it's finally working!
Thanks for replying!